# How to derive the three matrices of SVD from eigenvalue decomposition in Kernel PCA?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, eigenvalues, svd

Kernel PCA is usually done via eigenvalue decomposition of the Kernel Matrix $\mathbf{K}$ and standard PCA via SVD of the input $\mathbf{X}$.
In standard PCA as far as I know we can derive  $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{U}$ via two eigenvalue decompositions, of the Gram and Covariance/Correlation matrices:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
X=U\Sigma V^T\\
C=\dfrac{X^TX}{N-1}\\
G=\dfrac{XX^T}{N-1}\\
C=VE_CV^T\\
G=UE_GU^T\\
S=\sqrt{E_C(N-1)}\\
K=U_KE_KU^T\\
?=VE_?V^T
\end{array}
$$
But how does one get $\mathbf{V}$ in the case of a kernel? All posts I've ever read only discuss $\mathbf{U}$

**Note:**
I've read that $\mathbf{XV}=\mathbf{U\Sigma}$, however this relationship doesn't seem to hold for `numpy.linalg.svd` or `scipy.linalg.svd`

Comment: The nature of your question is unclear.  After all, once you have obtained $U$ and $\Sigma$ from $X$, $V$ is simply given by $V = X^\prime U^\prime \Sigma^{-1}.$

Comment: Where $X^\prime$ is the transpose ? Another way of phrasing what I'm asking is how does one get the *principal axes/directions* in Kernel PCA?

Comment: This would answer the question, however in SVD the $V$ matrix is $M\times M$ for an $N\times M$ input matrix $X$. The above should result in a $V$ with wrong dimension ($M\times N$). Something seems off

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up some transposes.  But you get the point: because $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal, you don't have to invert any matrices and you can recover $V$ from $X,$ $U,$ and $\Sigma.$  Thus, from $X=U\Sigma V^\prime,$ you obtain $V\Sigma U^\prime = X^\prime$ *via* transposition and thence $V = X^\prime U \Sigma^{-}.$

Comment: @whuber This is the answer I was looking for, though I can't seem to flag it as such. I'd also note (from wikipedia) $\Sigma$ is rectangular, not square as I thought $N \times M$ so this expression is valid

Answer (score 0):

Based on @whuber's answer it's simply:
$$
\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{X^TU\Sigma^{-1}}
$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).